# WAMPSERVER PHP MYSQL - (mysqlnd 5.0.10 error)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysqlnd

I am running WAMPSERVER (32 BITS & PHP 5.4) 2.4 
Apache : 2.4.4 MySQL : 5.6.12 PHP : 5.4.16 PHPMyAdmin : 4.0.4 SqlBuddy : 1.3.3 XDebug : 2.2.3
on a Windows XP box locally and getting the following error:

MySQL server 4.1.x, 5.1.x or above:

**mysqlnd 5.0.10 - 20111026 - $Id: e707c415db32080b3752b232487a435ee0372157 $**

also, I get an error on the top of my installation page that says:

**( ! ) Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\flynax\install\index.php on line 854**

I am a newbie and not sure if these two errors are related to each other or not. This is my first attempt to run a WAMP server and I would appreciate if I could get some help resolving this issue. Thank You

Comment: Your version of MySQL on your WAMP is too new, try installing an older version of MySQL

Answer (score 0):

It looks like everything is setup correctly to me and the output from mysqlnd doesn't look like an error.

The error you get comes from flynax using deprecated code, probably something like `$foo =& new Bar();` instead of `$foo = new Bar();`.
To solve this you can either:

- Change the code (but it's commercial software so maybe not the best thing to do);
- Downgrade PHP to version 5.x (but I don't know which version exactly and keeping your php up-to-date is always better);
- Disable the warning by changing the error reporting setting this in your php.ini to `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED`.

The last option is the best IMHO, as sooner or later the developers will update their code and hiding the warnings in the meantime won't hurt.

Comment: I tried with different versions of MySQL and PHP but the error didn't clear. I ended up removing WAMP and installing AMPPS which fixed the issue. Thanks for all your responses. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Search for mysql_get_client_info() install/index.php file to and change to mysql_get_server_info()